# Is there an generic way to synchronize multiple asynchronous results in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, asynchronous, synchronization

I've been wondering if we there is an native or generic way to synchronize multiple results from asynchronous HttpService calls in Adobe Flex. In other words, I need to recover some data from my server and execute an function after i recovered all the data from these different functions.

Here's an example:

```
private var mObj01 : Object = null;
private var mObj02 : Object = null;
private var mObj03 : Object = null;

public function TryLoadSynchronousFunction() : void
{
    if( mObj01 != null && mObj02 != null && mObj03 != null )
        DoSynchronizedStuff();
}

public function GetObj01( event : ResultEvent ) : void
{
    mObj01 = event.result as Object;
    TryLoadSynchronousFunction();
}

public function GetObj02( event : ResultEvent ) : void
{
    mObj02 = event.result as Object;
    TryLoadSynchronousFunction();
}

public function GetObj03( event : ResultEvent ) : void
{
    mObj03 = event.result as Object;
    TryLoadSynchronousFunction();
}

public function StartAsynchronous() : void
{
    myCall01.token = httpObj.Get01();
    myCall02.token = httpObj.Get02();
    myCall03.token = httpObj.Get03();
}
```

And on the `<fx:Declarations>` I would have:

```
<mx:CallResponder id="myCall01" result="GetObj01(event)" />
<mx:CallResponder id="myCall02" result="GetObj02(event)" />
<mx:CallResponder id="myCall03" result="GetObj03(event)" />
```

Is there a better approach to this kind of situation?

Comment: Thanks for your answers. @dtuckernet's answer looks a little easier to use in the code (from my point of view) but both answers were great. The only drawn back I found in both answers is the need of using a third party framework, but that's OK anyway. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin with, CallResponders are ok in demo code (such as the demo that Adobe provides), but in reality - this isn't a good implementation within an application.  You need to create some service delegates that handle all of your interaction with the server:

http://www.developria.com/2008/04/anatomy-of-an-enterprise-flex-8.html

Also, in this case, I would recommend looking at something like the chaining API with the Swiz framework as an option for chaining together a group of asynchronous tasks.

http://swizframework.jira.com/wiki/display/SWIZ/Chaining+API

Answer (score 1):

you can also use Task Framework of Parsley :

http://www.spicefactory.org/parsley/docs/2.4/manual/task.php#intro

It supports asynchronous Tasks.

```
var group:TaskGroup = new SequentialTaskGroup("some description for log output");
group.ignoreChildErrors = false;
group.addTask(new GetObj01Task());
group.addTask(new GetObj02Task());
group.addTask(new GetObj03Task());
group.addEventListener(TaskEvent.COMPLETE, doSynchronizedStuff);
group.addEventListener(ErrorEvent.ERROR, onError);
group.start();

public class GetObj01Task extends Task {

function SoundTask () {
    super();

    setCancelable(false);
    setSuspendable(false);
    setSkippable(false);    
}

protected override function doStart () : void {
     // do your http service call and register 
     // result handler on onComplete method and
     // fault handler on onError method
}

private function onComplete (event:Event) : void {
    // call task framework task success
    complete();
}

private function onError (event:ErrorEvent) : void {
    error("Error playing sound file " + filename + ": " + event.text);
}

}
```